# RAW device export

Tags: drawing, nfs, cifs

How can I export a RAW device for database use using NFS or CIFS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: you cannot!

Long answer:

Both NFS and CIFS are designed to handle files, not devices.

Exporting a device node on Unix using NFS will actually refer to a (maybe non-existent) device on the client, as far as the client's kernel is concerned. NFS is also notorious for locking issues that make anything concurrent (including DB transactions) a major problem. ACID on NFS is generally a no-no.

I believe CIFS has limited support for special files as well, although I may be mistaken.

Perhaps your are looking for something like NBD (Network Block Device), DRBD (Distributed Replicated Block Device) or even iSCSI?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISCSI

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_block_device

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DRBD

Keep in mind that there can be atrocious locking issues if you try to *share* a raw device to multiple nodes - you'd need to have support for distributed operation and locking all the way up to your database.

You would probably get more help if you explained what you want to do at a higher level...

Comment: filer exporting Raw devices for databases like oracle

Comment: @Albert: what are your requirements? What platforms (OS & DB) will you use? What will the purpose of using a device over a network be? Redudancy? Storage consolidation (e.g. to a SAN)?

Answer (score 2):

I remember doing this to fulfill some arcane requirement for an Oracle installation. I figured out how to make this happen but realized that under no circumstance would I want to actually implement this.

That said, if you like making bad choices:

Create an empty file that you're eventually going to expose as a raw device:

```
   dd if=/dev/zero of=/netapp/ocr/file bs=8k count=50000
```

Make a raw device:

```
mknod /dev/raw1 c 162 1
```

Create a loopback device that points to the file you want to use:

```
losetup /dev/loop1 /netapp/ocr/file
```

Bind the raw device to the loopback device:

```
raw /dev/raw/raw1 /dev/loop1
```

Produce output that can confirm the raw device is bound correctly:

```
raw -qa
```